# running a python script as Administrator in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have this small `Python` function:

```
  def change_boot(self):

        subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator','bcdedit'], shell=True)
```

However it keeps asking for the `admin` password ... how could i pass it as argument, or bypass it at all?

```
Enter the password for Administrator:
None
```

Comment: Redirect the `stdin` of the new process to your `stdout` and just print it

Comment: If you add the `/savecred` option to the script and then `runas` the script _manually_ once with the option (and supply the correct password when prompted), then it should use the saved credentials and not prompt for the password again.

Comment: @IonutHulub could you show me how?

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but maybe the easiest solution is to just run your script/app under an admin account.  Then you don't have to worry about it.  You can do this both for scheduled tasks and for services.

Comment: @DavidS can't ... the script is part of a multiboot solution for testing ... it will change the order in which windows boots